# Action link to the same page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create an html action link that is equalivent to

```
 <a href="#">Test Link</a>
```

or an action link to the current page. Anyone have any examples?

Comment: Why bother with an action link when `<a href="#" />` and `<a href="/" />` do the job?

Comment: You mean you don't want to go to the controller? Or you want to go to the current controller? There are actionlink overloads that default to the current controller.

Comment: i want the link to redirect to the page its currently in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I have a suggestion. Just put `<a href="#">Test Link</a>` in your view. The *only* reason to use `Html.ActionLink` is to resolve a URL dynamically. Here there's no need, so just use the HTML.

Answer (score 10):

You can try with this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(null)">Test Link</a>
```

The helper `Url.Action` with the first parameter in `null`, return the current action.

**Update for @MichaelLeanos's comment**

For MVC6:

```
<a href="@Url.Action()">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: @Url.Action(null) throws an exception using MVC 6. However, just using @Url.Action() works. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

just `pass null` for Controller Name, ActionMethod and Route arguments

take look it my snippet

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resource_en.DeleteDepartment,null,null,null, new { href="#", @class= "btn btn-danger" , data_id = department.ID  })
```

and the genrated HTML is

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" data-id="4" href="#">Delete Department</a>
```

if you dont pass `href="#"` in htmlArguments the href will be `href="/"` which will lead to `refresh the page` and meybe you dont want this thing

hope this help you

Comment: Just what I needed! This was useful when redirecting to the same page, but updating part of the URL (to change the display language)

Answer (score 1):

If this link will be added in a regular view (as oppose to a layout view), then you should know how to link to yourself.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "MyPage", "MyController")
```

This would not work if the link is on a layout page.

Comment: are you sure that this answer is for this question