# How to call controller's IActionResult methods without refreshing the web page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

To change the view, I'm calling the action which is present in my controller by using property : `asp-action=""` and `asp-controller=""`

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link text-white" aria-current="page">
                            <i class="fi fi-br-home"></i> Accueil
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AboutMe" class="nav-link text-white" aria-current="page">
                            <i class="fi fi-br-user"></i> Moi
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Resume" class="nav-link text-white" aria-current="page">
                            <i class="fi fi-br-physics"></i> CV
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Portfolio" class="nav-link text-white" aria-current="page">
                            <i class="fi fi-br-backpack"></i> Portfolio
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact" class="nav-link text-white" aria-current="page">
                            <i class="fi fi-br-address-book"></i> Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

This disturb be because it keeps refresh and reset my javascript code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Action link to the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718012/action-link-to-the-same-page)

Comment: Why don't you just send ajax request targeting controller-action endpoint? 
Then you can use the success data to manipulate your ui.

Also can you be more specific please? What do you mean by it resets your js code. You are navigating to different action so it is different view, different view means different javascript files as long as you don't use the same js come on every view.

Comment: @forth Hello Sir, well a simple example : I wrote a piece of code in js to allow me to add/delete active class to my different "a". Due to the refresh, it always reset it and never display the active "a" menu.